# spark-submit doesn't work with avtiva jdbc driver

Tags: apache-spark, spark-submit, druid

I am trying to write a spark job with simple query operation connecting to Druid. According to [Druid document](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/sql-jdbc.html),I am using avatica jdbc driver to connect to Druid.

Sample code:

```
object SimpleApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("SimpleApp").getOrCreate()
    val a = 15
    val b = 30
    val result = a * b
    println(s"Result is $result")
    val url = "jdbc:avatica:remote:url=http://<druidBrokerUrl>/druid/v2/sql/avatica/"
    val sql = "SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 5"
    val connectionProperties = new Properties
    val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, connectionProperties)
    val statement = connection.createStatement
    val resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql)
    while (resultSet.next) {
      println(resultSet.getString(5))
    }
    spark.stop()
}
```

I am able to connect to Druid when executing the scala code, but once I build the jar and try to run it using `spark-submit` I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.Driver'
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1429)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
        at DbConnection.<init>(SimpleApp.scala:43)
        at SimpleApp$.main(SimpleApp.scala:26)
        at SimpleApp.main(SimpleApp.scala)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:958)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1046)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1055)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.Driver
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:383)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:376)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1415)
        ... 15 more
```

I build the fat jar including `org.apache.calcite.avatica:avatica-core:1.21.0` and it is presented in the output jar. I also tried to run with `spark-submit --jars /path/to/avatica/jar`, but same error occurs.

I am really new to spark, hope to get some insight how to solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: I seem to remember having to specify additional jars in the executor extra class path parameter so that the JVM that is spawned as the executor has access to the jars you are passing in through --jars or --files. It's been a while, so I don't remember more specifics.

Comment: Did you try `spark-submit --packages "[OTHER DEPENDENCIES],org.apache.calcite.avatica:avatica:1.21.0"`?

Answer (score 0):

Try running `spark-submit` with path pointing to the jar, so something like `/path/avatica-xxx.jar`.